# Getting a list of all securities in a asset class on IBPY (Interactive Brokers API)

Tags: interactive-brokers, ibpy

Checked the google discussion groups and examples, most are already specifying a contract type.

Is it possible to get all the products in an asset class (or exchange)? For example 'CASH' for forex, or 'STK' for stocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not through the API but you can look it up on their website.
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1563

Some people have written screen scrapers, but it seems a little pointless.